# parent/closest .remove - jQuery

Tags: jquery, parent, closest

Everything in the jQuery is working, but not the .remove()
I've tried using .closest() and .parent() but neither worked

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#withdraw', function() {
    $.ajax({
         //ajax info
        },
        success: function(e) {
            if (e.type == 'error') {
                $("#bank .message").html(e.message).addClass('error').removeClass('showoff');
            } else {
                var total = parseInt($('#bank #total').html());
                $("#bank #total").html(total - 1);
                $(this).closest('li').remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<ul class="bank-items" id="bank-items">
    <li data-id="1">
        Item Name
        <a href="#" id="iteminfo" data-item="4" title="Information"><img src="..." alt="info" /></a>
        <a href="#" id="withdraw" data-id="1" title="Withdraw"><img src="..." alt="withdraw" /></a>
    </li>
    .
    .
    .
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `this` inside the success callback doesnot refer to the clicked anchor element, it is referring the ajax object.

One solution is to use the context option to pass a custom context for the callbacks like

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#withdraw', function () {
    $.ajax({
        //ajax info
        context: this,
        success: function (e) {
            if (e.type == 'error') {
                $("#bank .message").html(e.message).addClass('error').removeClass('showoff');
            } else {
                var total = parseInt($('#bank #total').html());
                $("#bank #total").html(total - 1);
                $(this).closest('li').remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Also note that, ID of an element must be unique, so if you have multiple `a#withdraw` element, use `withdraw` as a class not as ID.